# Take screenshots in GLUT

Tags: opengl, screenshot, glut

I have a GLUT application and I want to take a sequence of screen captures of the window so I can later put it into a movie. Is there a function that takes the contents of a window created by GLUT and puts it into an image file?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`glReadPixels()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) to grab the framebuffer and dump the result using your [favorite image handling library](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).

Comment: Stale URL.  Here's a fresh link to [glReadPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadPixels.xhtml).